# How to allow user to input/collect hashtags for message like Twitter | iOS | XCode

Tags: xcode, parse-platform, textfield, hashtag

I was wondering how I can program a collection interface that will collect an array of tags/hashtags for a message for example, much like Twitter and Instagram.

I would need to use a textfield or some collection mechanism. In a textfield, it seems that the user can input a string, but I would want to collect multiple tags.

Would I need to parse the input? What if one of the hashtags are more than one word?

Thank you

Comment: A text field for typing search string, a tableview to list search results.  Selection on the table view means selection of a tag, and a view (UILabel is a simple start) showing the tags selected so far.  Give it a go, and if you have any trouble with the programming, return to SO and ask a question about that.  As it stands this question is a classic close as opinion based or too broad.

Comment: I am asking how I can collect series of hashtags for a project. Such as #tag, #two, #three, etc. I am using Parse.com, and need to store those elements as an array collecting to the content object.

Answer (score 0):

This is very dependent on how you intend store, and later use the input. The quick answer is that you could allow them to input one string of multiple hashtags such as: '#stack #something #thirdtag' and then feed that right in to whatever will be consuming the hashtags.

If you need to consume one hashtag at a time, you can either parse the string and save each hashtag individually or use a repeating control to add hashtags one at a time. IE: "Add another hashtag" .

Comment: I am using Parse.com to share the information. You are right, I want to collect #one, #two, #three, #four, etc, and then store those objects as an array for each object.